Error with MAUI App trying to comunicate with localhost via port forwarding
I developed an app with MAUI Hybrid Blazor that connects to a server hosted on my PC through Google port forwarding. I have a strange problem though: as soon as I start the app, the request it sends is refused. However, if I try to reload the 'page' through the Google port forwarding tool, the request goes through successfully. And the app also starts to work fine on the phone, any suggestions about this?
I tried modifying the request sending in the code. Initially, a request was sent during the initialization of the Razor component. My attempt was to send a request every second until the response object where I store the incoming data is no longer null or until 10 attempts are exceeded, thinking it was a delay issue, that the app is not instantly ready to send requests, but it didn't work.

Could you provide related error message?

That's the error I get when I start the application from my phone, which disappears and everything goes well the moment I refresh the call from the Google port forwarding tool:
P.S i have to split it in multiple parts, it's too long
Connection refused (localhost:5084)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.d__1[[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()

at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<g__Core|12_0>d`2[[Shared.Components.DTOS.ToDoLists.GetAll.GetAllToDoListResponse, Shared.Components, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]].MoveNext()
at Shared.Components.Clients.ToDoListClient.GetAllAsync(HttpClient httpClient) in C:\Users\march\source\repos\esercizio22-05\Shared.Components\Clients\ToDoListClient.cs:line 16

at Shared.Components.Home.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\march\source\repos\esercizio22-05\Shared.Components\Home.razor:line 93
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
